# How to show datepicker when input is in readonly (to hide keyboard)

Tags: jquery-mobile

how to hide keyboard ?I googled it found use .this.blur().and use readonly="true".But when i used readonly.Then on click how to show date picker .I need to show date picker on date field and hide keyboard.

```
  <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="date" class="caseDate_h" readonly='true' >

$(document).on('click', '.caseDate_h', function() {
  //alert("00");
    $('.caseDate_h').datepicker('show');

});
```